# Concatenation not working in java

Tags: java

How String concatenation works in java?. This question is not for comparing Strings. Its for comparing objects and while concatenation i am getting only false. Why this is happen?
I have written a code for comparing the String references

```
public class StringClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        String s1 = new String("hello");
        String s2 = new String("hello");
        String s3 = "hello";
        String s4 = "hello";
        String s5 = "java";
        String s6 = "developer";
        String s7 = s5 + s6;
        String s8 = "java" + s6;
        String s9 = "javadeveloper";
        String s10 = "java" + "developer";

        System.out.println("s1 == s2 " + s1==s2);
        System.out.println("s3 == s4 " + s3 == s4);
        System.out.println("s7 == s9" + s7 == s9);
        System.out.println("s9 == s10" + s9==s10);
    }

}
```

In console i am getting like this

```
false
false
false
false
```

Why concatenation doesnt work in this code?. I am expecting the output like this

```
s1 == s2 false
s3 == s4 true
s7 = s9 false
s9 == s10 true
```

Comment: What's more likely, string concatenation is erroneous in Java or you are incorrectly comparing strings?

Comment: This is a mixture of misunderstanding about string comparison and operator precedence (`"s3 == s4 " + s3 == s4` is the same as `("s3 == s4 " + s3) == s4`).

Comment: I am not comparing strings i am comparing objects. My question is why concatenation is not working and i am new to java@ChiefTwoPencils

Comment: Thank  you @AndyTurner so plus operator having higher priority than comparison operator

Comment: @JinuPC https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: Apologies for coming across rudely. I was poorly suggesting that it's highly unlikely that the language is broken compared to it being a user error.

Comment: @JinuPC on a point of terminology, if you are really intending to compare *references* using `==`, "comparing the String *references*" would convey this better than "comparing the String *objects*".